# mysql filtering with limit a,b

Tags: mysql

I've an question about limit in mysql, I use queries

```
select id,name from tbl where id='2' order by name limit 1;
```

and

```
select id,name from tbl where id='2' order by name limit 1,2;
```

where the first query query shows the line, but the second don't show.
How to write query that works if i use "limit 1,2" instead of "limit 1". I use it with ajax, to make a paginatioin.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have more than 1 record with id = 2?

Comment: Did you read [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)? This is a syntax question and it's trivially answered there.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax of `LIMIT` is

```
LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}
```

(see [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html))

You added an offset of `1`, so it will skip the first (and only) hit. And thus you do not get any returned record!

Instead try to use

```
LIMIT 0,2
```

(although as there is (hopefully!) one record with `id='2'` it makes not much sense to use `LIMIT`)

Comment: instead of `LIMIT 1,2` you can also write `LIMIT 2 OFFSET 1`

Answer (score 2):

you have the id=2 this will give you one record.

if you have more ids with id=2 then you can use LIMIT 1,2

here an example of limit

```
      SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 0, 10 

    //This will display the first 10 results from the database.

      SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 5, 5 

      //This will show records 6, 7, 8, 9, and 10
```

and in your case

```
     limit 1   <---- will show the first record in your table
     limit 1,2 <----will show records first and second  in your table
```

if your id is autoincrement , u dont need limit here because its already unique